# Proof that $∂A \cap A =\emptyset \iff A^\circ = A \iff A$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I've already proved the other direction, but have some doubts about the direction $∂A \cap A =\emptyset \iff A^\circ = A \iff A$ is open. Please take a look at my proof and let me know what you think. To me this statement looks "too obvious to prove", hence it doesn't seem so easy.

**Proof**:

Suppose that $∂A \cap A =\emptyset$. Since $∂A \cap A^\circ =\emptyset$ and $A^\circ$ is the largest open set contained in $A$, $A^\circ = A. \implies A$ is open.

I'm afraid my attempt doesn't look rigorous enough.

Comment: Which direction ? You use $\iff$…

Comment: You could decrease the confusion by not using a union symbol when you mean intersection. And clean up the arrows as Bernard suggests.

Comment: what do you mean by $∂A$?

Comment: $\partial A$ denotes the boundary of $A.$

Comment: @sinbadh: I suppose it's the boundary. The O.P.'s question may be  trivial, depending on the definition used.

Comment: Yes, it is. For that reason it is my doubt @Bernard

Comment: What's your definition of the boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your deffinition of $\partial A$, you can prove that $\partial A=\overline{A}\backslash A^\circ$ FOR ALL $A$. Then, for all $A$ we have $\partial A\cap A=(\overline{A}\backslash A^\circ)\cap A=(\overline{A}\cap A)\backslash A^\circ=A\backslash A^\circ$.

So, $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset$ iff $A\backslash A^\circ=\emptyset$ and the result follows.